# For my C code, I am not sure how the binary tree is looping because my expected output is different then the actual output?

Tags: loops, pointers, tree, binary-tree, nodes

I am tracing part of a code given by the professor but I don't understand how the binary tree is working. The question is: "Write a function to find the lowest common ancestor in a binary search tree and return a pointer. Lowest common ancestor between two nodes a and b in tree T is defined as
the lowest node in T that has both a and b as descendants.
Consider the following tree as an example. the lowest common ancestor of 4 and 8 is 6. lowest common ancestor of 4 and 14 is 10."

```
        10
     6     14
   4  8  12  16
```

My question is I don't understand how it is looping?

```
node *lca(node *ptr, int a, int b)
{
    if(ptr==NULL)
        return NULL;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {   
        if (ptr->key >= a && ptr->key <= b)//What's key?
            return (ptr);
        else if (ptr->key > b)
            ptr = ptr->left;
        else if (ptr->key < a)
            ptr = ptr->right;
    }
    return (ptr);
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem with that code or you just need explanation what is he doing and how?

Comment: @Suma the code is fine. I hope since the professor gave it. I need an explanation on what he is doing and how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of this code is as follow:

Assuming the tree is binary sorted, we can check if the `a` and `b` element are on different side of the current node (if the are we found our lca).

In binary tree, for each node, the bigger element going right and the small ones left. So, if `a`is smaller from current node and b is bigger, its mean they are from different side -> lca.

The `ptr->key` is accessing the data in the node.

When the first `if` statement fails it mean both a and b are from the same side -> the next 2 if statement choose if the continue the search right or left (is b smaller then current node both at the left side and if a bigger then current both on the right side)

**Notice** this code assume that a is smaller than b.

Comment: setting a=4 ,b=8 ,       
~~~
if (ptr->key >= a && ptr->key <=b)//first key is 10 so 10>=4 8<=14
   return (ptr);//statement is true so it will return 10 but it should be 6 //what am I doing wrong??
~~~

Comment: If first key is 10 the first if statement fails as 4<10 BUT 8 is not bigger the 10 - failing the first if bring us to the else scope where the statement is true as 10 bigger then 8. And then the while loop continue with next node as 6 which true for first if (both 4 smaller than 6 and 8 bigger than 6)